# My navbar is not moving to the right with mr-auto?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I use mr-auto to try and move the navbar to the right but its not working. I'm not sure why. Can anyone explain.
Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="/img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <div class="mr-auto"></div>
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contigency Plans</a>
                  </li>
```

Comment: Your #navbar element should have position 'fixed' or 'absolute' and `right = 0` to stick on the right, try to understand CSS position before start using Bootstrap. the following video can help you => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jx5jmI0UlXU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
#navbarNav{
      text-align: right;
    }
```

and also instead of this

```
<div class="collapse navbar collapse"id="navbarNav"> use this 

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn’t your `mr-auto` be a part of the `<ul class=“navbar-nav”`>? Such as `<ul class=“navbar-nav mr-auto”>`.